Name of a topological property, reference
Given a topological Hausdorff space $X$, the property I'm interested is the following:

For every subset $A \subseteq X$, $|\mathrm{cl}(A)| = |A|$. In other words, for every subset $A$ of $X$, the cardinality of the closure of $A$ is the same as the cardinality of $A$.

An example of such a space is any ordinal space, i.e. any ordinal with its order-topology. I wonder whether this property has a name or is equivalent to some known topological property.
EDIT: Of course, as pointed out in the comments, this notion is trivial unless the space is uncountable. So we can restrict to this case.

I don't think there's a standard name for that... The only thing coming to my mind is the notion of perfect set/space: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/perfect+space A space with only perfect subsets would satisfy that property xD

The rational numbers also have the property. Finite sets are already closed, and infinite sets are already maxed out on the cardinality. The same holds for the "smaller sets are closed" topology, such as cofinite (on countable sets) or cocountable (on a set of size $\aleph_1$).

Any $T_1$ countable space satisfies the condition. And any such space must be $T_1$.

As pointed out in the comments, this is interesting for uncountable spaces, only.
If $X$ is $T_1$ and $|X| = \aleph_1$, then the condition is equivalent to: the closure of each countable subset is countable. This condition is equivalent to anti-separability, see here, Proposition 2.1.
